# T-SQL Check if table exists in schema

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, schema

So far I've been using the format below for creating/updating tables

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM sysobjects WHERE name = 'table_name' AND type = 'U') 
DROP TABLE [dbo].[table_name]
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[table_name]()
GO
```

But recently I came across a case where two schemas have a table with the same name. How can I check if the table exists in a specific schema? Its only the part`SELECT 1 FROM sysobjects WHERE name = 'table_name' AND type = 'U'` that needs fixing, I've changed the rest to:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM sysobjects WHERE name = 'table_name' AND type = 'U') 
DROP TABLE [schema_name].[table_name]
GO
CREATE TABLE [schema_name].[table_name]()
GO
```

My current server version is `2008R2` so I would prefer answers that also work for that version. I have many other checks is done this way so I don't really want to completely change this pattern.

Comment: Consider using the more concise `OBJECT_ID` function: `IF OBJECT_ID(N'[schema_name].[table_name]') IS NOT NULL...`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the `schemas` object as well. For example:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1
           FROM sys.tables t
                JOIN sys.schemas s ON t.schema_id = s.schema_id
           WHERE s.[name] = N'schema_name'
             AND t.name = N'table_name'
             AND t.type = 'U')
    DROP TABLE [schema_name].[table_name];
GO
```

Comment: @nickzoum personally, I suggest the `OBJECT_ID` answer from S.Jose. It is far more succinct.

Comment: Every other check is done this way. I don't really want to completely change the pattern. I also spotted a u_id variable in `sysobjects` is that not the same as `schema_id` in `sys.tables`?

Comment: Fair enough. Might be worth while in the future if you do want to make it more succinct though :)

Answer (score 12):

TRY

```
IF OBJECT_ID('[schema_name].[table_name]') IS NOT NULL
        DROP TABLE [schema_name].[table_name]
    GO
```

Answer (score 5):

Use this syntax.

`DROP TABLE IF EXISTS [schema_name].[table_name]`

Comment: Note that `DROP...IF EXISTS` requires SQL Server 2016 or later.